# Add a calendar event via Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I am trying to get a Google API calendar entry to work via a form. I have enabled the API in the script and on the dashboard.

I have two issues, calling the create event function from the main script and getting the variables to work between both.

I have noted out the basic variant of the create event script, as once I get it working I need the more advanced functions of the full API.

The main script works with the noted out section, but I cannot get the API method to work no matter what I try, and searching has not given me any answers.

Any help will be very gratefully received

Thanks

```
function onSubmit(e){
  var formResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var submitterEmail = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var submitionDate = e.response.getTimestamp();
  var eventName = formResponses[0].getResponse();
  var eventDescription = formResponses[1].getResponse();
  var moduleCode = formResponses[2].getResponse();
  var organiser = formResponses[3].getResponse();
  var organiserEmail = formResponses[4].getResponse();
  var eventRoom = formResponses[5].getResponse();
  var techTeam = formResponses[6].getResponse();
  var supportRequired = formResponses[7].getResponse();
  var supportDescription = formResponses[8].getResponse();
  var eventRepeat = formResponses[9].getResponse();
  if(techTeam=="Performance Studios"){var calId = "Redacted"};
  if(techTeam=="Televison Studios"){var calId = "TV Calendar"};
  if(techTeam=="Science and Publishing"){var calId = "Science Calendar"};
  var finalDescription = 'Organiser: ' + organiser + '\n \n' + 'Module Code: ' + moduleCode + '\n \n' + 'Description of the Event: ' + eventDescription  + '\n \n' + 
        'Type of support: ' + supportRequired + '\n \n' + 'Description of Support: ' + supportDescription + '\n \n'; 
  var calendarId =  CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);  
  // create attachments

      //Single Day Event 
      if(eventRepeat=="Single Day Event")
      {
      var supportDate   = (formResponses[10].getResponse());
      var supportStart = (formResponses[11].getResponse());  
      var eventStart = formResponses[12].getResponse();
      var eventEnd = formResponses[13].getResponse();
      var supportEnd = (formResponses[14].getResponse());  
      var start = new Date(supportDate+"T"+supportStart+":00.000Z");
      var end = new Date(supportDate+"T"+supportEnd+":00.000Z"); 
      if (end<start){var end = new Date(end.setDate(end.getDate()+1))};
      if (eventStart!=""){var finalDescription = eventName + ' Start Time: ' + eventStart +'\n' + eventName + ' End Time: ' + eventEnd + '\n \n' + 'Organiser: ' + organiser + '\n \n' + 'Module Code: ' + moduleCode + '\n \n' + 'Description of the Event: ' + eventDescription  + '\n \n' + 'Type of support: ' + supportRequired + '\n \n' + 'Description of Support: ' + supportDescription + '\n \n'}; 
      //calendarId.createEvent(eventName,start, end,{description: finalDescription, location: eventRoom, guests: submitterEmail +' , '+ organiserEmail, sendInvites:true}); 
      };




};   


function createEvent() { 

            var event = {
            summary: eventName,
            location: eventRoom,
            start: {dateTime: start},
            end: {dateTime: end},
            // Bold Red background.
            colorId: 11
                  };


      event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
};
```

Comment: Do you see any errors returned? Have you tried creating events with fewer parameters (maybe something's wrong with one of them)?
Also, maybe this could help you: http://www.googleappsscript.org/calendar-services/create-calendar-events-by-submitting-form

Comment: The calendarId appears to be undefined in the createEvent() function.  Where is calId in submit Function?